# Assign different Domains to different nodes in one Umbraco instance

Tags: umbraco, web-hosting, umbraco7, multiple-domains

Currently i have 2 Domains i want to use in 1 Umbraco instance.

1. [www.im-tas.de](http://www.im-tas.de) and the
2. [www.mainzercarre.de](http://www.mainzercarre.de)

This is the Node Structure and the domains i want to assign

[image]

This is how my hostnames currently looks like for both nodes

this is the imtas configuration
[image]

and this from mainzercarre.de
[image]

But it does not work. this is the error i get
[image]

In my server settings i already assigned both domains to the same folder. i also checked the permission setting but i am not sure.

What i am doing wrong

Comment: I think you should move mainzercarre.de to the root. Not sure if that should work but I have never seen a child domain of another domain. Umbraco might get confused which route to respond to.

Comment: I could fix the issue. I had to republish the content type and the error disapeared. i dont know the reason but found a suggestion in another forum